# In spring security how to read role @PreAuthorize("hasRole") from property file

Tags: spring, spring-security

controller code as follows:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('${ddraft.select}')")
 public String showCloseDrafts(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
 return ROCSConstants.CLOSE_DRAFTS_PAGE;
}
```

roles.properties file has the following entry:

```
ddraft.select=ROLE_REF015M
```

I tried the following but without any success:

```
 - @PreAuthorize("hasRole('${ddraft.select}')")
 - @PreAuthorize("hasRole( ${ddraft.select})")
```

Comment: try using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(${ddraft.select})")`, or is your property file getting loaded..??, p lus do not give spaces

Comment: i did try without the spaces but with no success.   I am able to read the values from property file using the @Value, so I am sure that's not the problem.

Comment: does it gives any error/exception

Comment: I get the following:    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Comment: its giving the following: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'hasRole(#{ddraft.select})'